# Matching Mercurial/Python/PyWin32 Component Versions

Tags: python, mercurial, pywin32, hgweb

I'm looking at two different guides for Windows HgWeb installation on IIS.  The [first from mercurial developers](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep) says:

> On Windows, your Python version must
>   match the version used to compile
>   Mercurial. Otherwise, you'll get
>   "Invalid Magic Number" errors when
>   trying to run the CGI.

The [second guide](http://www.firegarden.com/software/hosting-mercurial-repo-iis7-windows-server-2008r2-x64-python-isapi-cgi) says:

> Don’t waste time monkeying around with
>   the installers. You need a version of
>   Mercurial matching your Python install
>   so get the source code!

This is all great, except nobody wants to tell you how to match versions of Python and Mercurial.  I see no guide that gives a map correlating version numbers.  That is my primary need.  For example, I'm using Mercurial 1.9.  I have no idea what version of Python goes with that.  The second guide says my version of PyWin32 must match as well.  Great.

If the version-match info is not available online, is there a command I can issue to Hg that will dump all this info on me?

In the mean time, I've found that I can't build the Mercurial source code (is this because I don't have a properly matching version of Python?).

Comment: It looks like it just means you need to know if you want the 64 bit or 32 bit (x86) version. If you know which option you picked for installing Python, I'd just go ahead and try the mercurial installer. Remember the guide is just one person's opinion.

Answer (score 0):

#### HgWeb

For HgWeb, [this Mercurial download page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download) recommends using the version that installs Mercurial as python modules, requiring Python 2.6.

From that, you would select a build of [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) and choose the download for Python 2.6, as they build it for several versions.

Both decisions also have 32bit and 64bit versions.

#### Building

The [main Mercurial download page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads) hints that Python 2.4 through 2.7 are supported, so you might try building with 2.6 or 2.7 if you still wish to build it yourself. The wiki page for [building on Windows](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WindowsInstall) is dated, mentioning Mercurial 1.3, but also mentions Python 2.6.